# Make wreturn-type an error, not a warning?

Tags: c++, g++

I am on `gcc`, it gave me a warning that i forgot a return value in a function with `Wreturn-type`.

However, I don't want it to be a warning, I want it to be an actual compiler error. Is there a way to stop compiling when `Wreturn-type` is encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to stop compiling when Wreturn-type is encountered?

You can make any warning an error with:

```
-Werror=return-type
```

You can make gcc "stop" compiling on errors with:

```
-Wfatal-errors
```

Make sure to read [your compiler documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options).